# Flask App with Gunicorn on Nginx Server Error On POST

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I am new to Python . I hosted the Flask app which will be accepting a POST request with Gunicorn on Nginx Server on EC2 instance.

When I post on the route I am getting error as :

```
1578#0: *14 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: myip, server: serverip, request: "POST /train HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/ec2-user/myproject/myproject.sock:/save_data", host: "serverip"
```

The POST request is not from the same domain and will always be from some other domain. Do I need to add something on my nginx.conf file?

Everything works fine when I run app using the command python app.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue. This wasn't related to my NGINX configuration (which I initially thought was the cause).

The problem resided in my Gunicorn configuration file.

In my Gunicorn config file (`/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service`), I added the following to my `ExecStart` line:

`--timeout 600`

The file now looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=harrison
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/harrison/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/harrison/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/harrison/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --timeout 600 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Furthermore, the reason why you do not experience the issue when launching your app using `python app.py` is because it is not being served by Gunicorn that way... it's using the Flask test development server. The development server does not have the same timeout duration as Gunicorn. By default, I believe the Gunicorn timeout defaults to 30 seconds. In the case of my application, this was far too low.

Comment: Yes!! you saved my life.... Thank you so much. I have google every page and stuck on this from tomorrow. I had created 8 instance of EC2 and changed what should not be changed.